# Lo-Dash _.has nested inside _.every not returning what I expect

Tags: javascript, lodash

I assume I'm missing something obvious, but in this code snippet using Lo-Dash:

```
var collection = [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 3, "bar": 4}];

var result = _.every(collection, function(testObj) {
    _.has(testObj, "foo");
});

console.log(result);
```

I would expect result to be true, but it evaluates to false. Here's a fiddle if you want to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/XcZnd/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `return` the result of `_.has` from the callback.

Comment: Haha, I knew it was something obvious. Thanks!